# if-statement in for-loop not working

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, if-statement, random

So I'm writing a script that can tell if an action has already been performed. I started off with a 2x2 array with 0s in it. I wanted to randomly store three 1s among the four elements and if the element is already storing 1, echo Repeated to notify the user. This is the code I have so far and it doesn't echo Repeated even if the same element is chosen more than once.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::Creating a 2x2 zero array
for /l %%y in (0,1,1) do (
    for /l %%x in (0,1,1) do (
        set map[%%x][%%y]=0
    )
)
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::Putting 1s in elements randomly
for /l %%x in (1,1,3) do (
    set /a j=!Random!%%2
    set /a i=!Random!%%2
    if !map[%i%][%j%]! EQU 0 (set map[!i!][!j!]=1) else (echo Repeated)
)
::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::Result
echo !map[0][0]!!map[1][0]!
echo !map[0][1]!!map[1][1]!
echo.
pause
```

I read something related online and am pretty sure it has something to do with the "setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion" thing but I don't know how to do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may use `for /F "tokens=1,2" %%i in ("!i! !j!") do if !map[%%i][%%j]! EQU 0 (set map[%%i][%%j]=1) else ...`. This type of management is fully described at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990)

Comment: Thanks for your sugguestion but can you explain what "for /F "tokens=1,2" %%i in ("!i! !j!") do" means? I'm still new to batch. I just tried your code, it didn't show how many times it repeated tho

Comment: You may type `for /?` at the command-prompt and read the help screen, or review anyone of the numerous descriptions about `for` command that exists in the web, like [this](https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) or [this](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/ntcmds_shelloverview.mspx?mfr=true), etc... In this case, it assigns the value of `!i!` and `!j!` into `%%i` and `%%j`, so `!map[%%i][%%j]!` could be correctly used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for /l %%x in (1,1,3) do (
    set /a j=!Random!%%2
    set /a i=!Random!%%2
    SET /a s=map[!i!][!j!]
    if !s! EQU 0 (set map[!i!][!j!]=1) else (echo Repeated)
)
```

In your code, `%i%` and `%j%` will each be resolved to *nothing* since neither `i` nor `j` is set when the `for` is encountered - `%var%` means "the value of `var` when the block is **started**" hence your `if` is resolved to `if !map[][]! EQU 0 ...` - `map[][]` is a valid varname.

To access the value of the variable *as it changes with the block's operation* (ie the "run-time" value) you need to use `!var!` with `delayed expansion` in operation. This would yield (theoretically)

```
if !map[!i!][!j!]! EQU 0 (set map[!i!][!j!]=1) else (echo Repeated)
```

**BUT** this won't work since there is no way for `cmd` to resolve which pairs of `!` to resolve first (it will choose `!map[!`,`!][!` and `!]!` reulting in `if ij equ 0 ...` which will obviously always fail)

So - I chose to set `s` to the value extracted from `map` and then test *that*.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have been stuck at this for a day and I did try "if !map[!i!][!j!]! EQU 0 (set map[!i!][!j!]=1) else (echo Repeated)" and it doesn't work. Never knew that I can set s to the value to do that.

Comment: Although this answer solves this problem, it is not a general solution. i.e. this method does not work if the array have non-numeric values...